# Crack-it and Modular Tree addons are not appearing blender 2.81a

Tags: add-on

Thanks for the help in advance. I am new to Blender and trying to add the Addons Crack It and Modular Tree, but I can't get them to appear on the tool bar. They seem to load fine and without warnings, and I can seem them under tools> work-space - screen shot attached. What am I missing or doing incorrectly.

[image]

Comment: Have you enabled them in the preferences and are they compatible with Blender 2.8x?

Comment: Google is suggesting that "crack it addon is now integrated with fracture cell addon" https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-crack-it-make-crack-for-tree-poop-rock-etc/673393/35  and the Modular Tree addon is found in the  List of Editors (viewports) https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=226&v=UQx0eh8z-iM&feature=emb_logo.